# testing a javascript library with jasmine

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I'm working on a little library: https://github.com/jtmkrueger/lilBox and am trying to add some jasmine tests. From what I've gathered, I just need to add a `require` statement at the top of the spec to include the file, like this:

```
require('../lilbox.js');

describe("lilBox", function() {
  it ("is loaded", function () {
    expect(lilBox).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

But that test is failing. I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, but I think it has to do with how I'm including the file.

What do I need to do to get this test to pass?

Comment: how does your export statement look like in lilbox.js?

Comment: @Brian check out https://github.com/jtmkrueger/lilBox/blob/master/lilbox.js#L4 I think that's what you're talking about.

Comment: It's best to allow questions to stand on their own.

Comment: this should work: var lilBox = require('../lilbox');

Comment: thanks @Brian that's all it took to get my test to pass! If you add your comment as an answer, I'll gladly accept.

Comment: great! good to see people working on opensource projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lilbox similar to a package:

```
var lilBox = require('../lilbox');
```

It's case sensitive if i'm not mistaken, and functions can be called using lilBox.fn(). Have fun testing the app